# Should I write unit-test for every public method?

Tags: java, unit-testing, language-agnostic, junit

Should I write unit-test for every public method? For example I have a CRUD service, so I have 
`create, read, update, delete` methods.  But when I write test to `delete` or `update` methods, I implicitly test `read` and `create` methods (for example to test the `update` method first I need create an entity(`create`), then retrieve it (`read`), then `update` it and then retrieve it again to ensure it changed).

Comment: please explain, why this question isn't constructive?

Comment: You should test everything that requires testing. Personally I would test every case here, just to confirm the combination works as well as the individual operations.

Comment: It's not constructive in the sense that this kind of question ends up in a debate. This is not a debate site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would write tests for `get` and `create`, yes:

- It makes it easier to separate behaviour you're *deliberately* testing from behaviour you're *incidentally* testing
- It makes it easier to test failure conditions and other scenarios that aren't covered by your other methods
- It means if you change your implementation of `delete` / `update` to *not* use `get` / `create`, you're still testing `get` / `create`

Ideally, I'd attempt (without getting too hung up about it) to make the tests set and check the data at the "lower" level - e.g. performing direct in-memory database access. That way you're really testing "If I create an entity, the data in the database looks like {this}" (and likewise when fetching). Just being able to create and then get the same results again is fine in terms of *black box* testing, but I typically think of unit tests as more white box.

Answer (score 1):

**Should I write unit-test for every public method?** Yes

Writing a test case for each public method is best thing. To test **delete** operation you should call **create test** first and then call **delete test** method. This way your delete test method will be independent and you can test all possible scenrio.

Comment: `you should call create test first and then call delete test method`.. hmm.. is really  my test methods should depend on each other?

Comment: no..in this case create is like setup. You are just ensuring that object which you want to delete is actually available.